# Java "static import" vs. "import static" in Java 8

Tags: java, static, import, java-8

I was trying to use use static imports on Java, but I was writing it wrong

```
static import java.lang.System.out;
```

And the code compiled (although the "out" symbol couldn't be found), no syntax errors.

So, what does the "static import" actually means?

Comment: Really?  That should be a syntax error according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/syntax.html -- the keyword import can only begin an import declaration.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me... what IDE are you using?

Comment: Also, where did you put that line of code? Eclipse gives me an error whether I place it above a class declaration or inside a class.

Comment: @pst - This should be flagged as a syntax error irrespective of whether the identifier being imported exists ...

Comment: So it is a bug, I'm using Sun's Java 8 (SDK 1.8) preview for Mac OS X. It should be a syntax error there (even if the "out" symbol isn't found, because if I use System.out.println, with the "static import", the program compiles without error or warning).

Comment: @PauloTorrens - Ah!  This might be a compiler bug, or it might be a change in the Java 8 language that I'm not aware of.  JLS 8 is not yet available / finalized.

Comment: I doubt it is a language change: having both "static import" and "import static" would be too confusing.

Comment: No language changes in this area are contemplated for Java 8. Seems like a bug. Please file it. Thanks.

Comment: how were you trying to compile no way it compiles you should added more info OS, etc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should not compile.

```
static import java.lang.System.out;
```

According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3), a single static import should look like this:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

All forms of the Java import statement *start with* the `import` keyword, and I don't think there is any other context (i.e. apart from an import statement) in which the `import` keyword can be used.

<sub>Note: the `import` and `static` keywords are not modifiers in this context, so the "modifiers can be supplied in any order" meta-rule does not apply here.</sub>

---

In short, either your compiler / IDE is broken or confused ... or what you are looking at is not real Java source code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access static member of a class, you have to use the full class name that contains it.  For example, to access the `pi` value in the `Math` class, you have to use `java.lang.Math.PI`.  But, if you import it (`import static java.lang.Math.PI`), you can use just use `PI` in your code to access it.