# static member in Java

Tags: java

```
package pack1;

public class A {
    public static int i = 10;

    public static void test()  {
    System.out.println("done");
    }

 }



//this is other .class file
package pack2;
import static pack1.A;  
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Manager2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
           out.println(i);
           test();
  }
}
```

Whenever I use `import static pack1.A;` as I have used in class Manager2 instead of
`import static pack1.A.*;`, the compiler shows an error. Doesn't `import static pack1.A;`   import class A including static members?

I'm aware of that using `import static pack1.A.i` imports static members, but 'import static pack1.A;' is showing an error.

Comment: Because that's how the language is specified. Either you import all static members using *, or you import one static member at a time. Statically importing the class itself is not legal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java "static import" vs. "import static" in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410681/java-static-import-vs-import-static-in-java-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/) only describes two different approaches to static imports.

[Single-Static-Import declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3) of the form `import static TypeName . Identifier ;` which *"imports all accessible static members with a given simple name from a type"*.

The [Static-Import-on-Demand declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4) allows *"all accessible static members of a named type to be imported as needed"*, and is of the form `import static TypeName . * ;`.

Essentially you have to specify all the method names that you wanted imported, or use the `.*` notation if you want to be able to use any method as required.